# How to gradually change the saturation of a color in python turtle

Tags: python, drawing, python-turtle

I would like to make a color change its saturation. Like when you first draw a color (red), then you make it a little lighter so that it doesn't become white right away. It slowly gets lighter and lighter until it is the color white.
Its not this post:
[Changing the color gradually turtle (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373335/changing-the-color-gradually-turtle-python)
because it is changing the color instantly.

I tried this:

```py
colors = ["red","white"]
for i in range(2):
   turtle.color(colors[i])
   turtle.circle(100)
done()
```

but it immediately changes the color which is what I don't want.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want a hollow circle that's drawn instantly, and gradually grows lighter, or do you want the circle to be drawn slowly like this? Either way, using RGB mode is probably the way to go. Color strings like `"red"` don't have an easy way to adjust lightness. See also [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)--it's good to ask a specific technical question like "How can I change the color gradually?" (your title does this well)

Comment: For the record, you aren't changing the color of any circles. You are drawing a circle over the circle before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you face is that the circle method is doing it's own thing. Once that routine starts there doesn't seem to be a way to affect any of it's properties while it is drawing. This means you have to get creative and make your own circle drawing function. The below is an example that gets you in the ballpark.

```py
import turtle as t
from math import cos, sin, radians


# gradients
RED_GRAD   = [f'#{(c<<20|c<<16):06x}' for c in range(0, 16)]
GREEN_GRAD = [f'#{(c<<12|c<<8):06x}' for c in range(0, 16)]
BLUE_GRAD  = [f'#{(c<<4|c):06x}' for c in range(0, 16)]

CC_TRIGGER = 360//15 # degrees to draw before going to next color


def move_pen(x:int, y:int) -> None:
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()


def draw_circle(radius:int, x:int, y:int, thickness:int=2, gradient:list=RED_GRAD, speed:float=5) -> None:
    speed = max(1, min(5, speed))  # constrain speed
                                   
    t.tracer(1.6*speed, 3.2*speed) # set speed
    t.width(thickness)             # set line thickness
                                   
    move_pen(x + radius, y)        # set pen at drawing start location
                                   
    # draw circle                  
    for i in range(1, 361):        
        t.settiltangle(i+90)       # emulate turtle behavior for circle method

        # change color 
        t.color(gradient[i//CC_TRIGGER])

        # draw step
        r = radians(i)
        t.goto(radius * cos(r) + x, radius * sin(r) + y)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    draw_circle(50, 0, 0, gradient=BLUE_GRAD, speed=1.3)
    t.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can speed this up with `tracer()` and `update()`.

Comment: @ggorlen - well, I just sped it up by allowing it to draw more than one degree at a time, sacrificing resolution. I have the docs open. I will look at `tracer` and `update` and see what I can do. My answer will be updated if I come up with a solution. For the record, I have never used turtle graphics. I'm just spinning this up out of the docs and "common sense".

Comment: There's also `t.speed("fastest")` but it may still be hard to control. I asked OP to clarify how fast they want the drawing to be. I'd expect they want the drawing to be instantaneous rather than animated.

Comment: @ggorlen - I sped it up a lot with `tracer`. I attempted to allow for a settable speed that homogenizes one number into the 2 numbers that `tracer` requires. It's probably a bit silly, and definitely not based on any real logic, but it works.

Comment: Usually I use `tracer(0)`, then `update()` to render, controlled with `ontimer`, but this may be overkill.

Comment: @ggorlen - I have run out of time to play with this question, but I am interested in getting these little details correct. I need to go shuck oysters for 12 hours (yeah, I really am an oyster shucker). Maybe I'll have some energy when I get home, and I can refactor a thing or 2.